# Set Width full 100% item sub menu in TB_Megamenu Drupal 7

Tags: navigation

I used module tb_megamenu Drupal 7 which version "7.x-1.0-rc2" ! I had three item submenu . The first and second sub show list text ,but three sub show all group. I want three sub menu set width 100% ! But this problem not support in UI TB Mega menu ! So if I want change item submenu width 100% how to change or fix it !

Thanks !